# Maven plugin as transitive dependency

Tags: java, maven, plugins, maven-plugin, dependency-management

Is it possible to use a Maven plugin as a transitive dependency?

Say we have a `common.jar` project which is used as a dependency in `productservice` app, in that `common` project we configured some maven plugins that we want to use in `productservice`. How can we refer to those pre-configured plugins so we don't have to configure them again in `productservice`.

Thanks

Comment: Using a parent pom which contains the configurations. Usually in companies you have a corporate parent which contains default configurations for plugins (most important define all versions of them) and maybe supplemental configurations ...maybe you need different parent for different purposes...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for your suggestion but I would like to avoid maintaining another project just for this task. If it's not possible to extract plugins configuration from a .jar I'll copy/paste will do the job, sadly.

Comment: A dependency is related to dependencies but not build configuration which includes plugin configuration etc.. In corporate environments it is the usual way having a separate parent pom project which is used for a larger number of projects. I have my own parents for my own projects....that's in the end easier and reduces the maintenance burden https://github.com/khmarbaise/smpp...

Comment: You can try playing with dependency type "pom" (instead of the default "jar") for the 'common' project. However, I think this only helps with dependency management, not sure if plugins are taken over too..

Comment: @TiberiuDorianMoşescu They are not.

Comment: @TiberiuDorianMoşescu That will not work cause you have to have the scope `import` which is not a dependency...and also will not use the plugin configurations etc.